# How to POST reviews using WooCommerce REST API

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, woocommerce-rest-api

Please how do one post reviews using WooCommerce REST API? I read [the documentation](http://woothemes.github.io/woocommerce-rest-api-docs/) but I couldn't find it. I mean, what format will the URL be for making the post request?

Comment: [It isn't supported yet](https://github.com/woothemes/woocommerce/issues/10788) by the api.

Comment: Did you find any solution yet?

Comment: @Ashiq The last time I checked. Posting reviews wasn't supported.

Comment: I'm looking for cart listing API too, but didn't find!